# Cocos2d V3 CCLayer replacement?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Using `cocos2d v2` i was able to set some other class as a layer , and add it to some scene.
I did it with :

```
BackgroundLayer *background=[[BackgroundLayer alloc] init];
[self addChild:[background set]]; //returns a Node
```

Where the background layer was a `CCLayer` .
Now i am trying to do the exact same where the background layer is a `CCNode` ,
but it wouldn’t add it to the other scene , just perform its Init method .

How would i add some other `CCNode` class to another CCScene class as a layer  ?

Thanks ,

Answer (score 4):

CCLayer no longer exists in Cocos2d V3, to be honest I see no reason for CCLayer anyways.

I think you are looking for CCNodeColor in this case.

For example:

```
CCScene *scene = [[CCScene alloc] init];
CCNodeColor *nodeColor = [CCNodeColor nodeWithColor:[CCColor redColor]];
[scene addChild:nodeColor];
```